# Combine 2 Variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

how i can combine the 2 variables torso and comb to access the the string in the array correctly

```
var comb = new Array("MT 1.1","MT 1.2","MT 1.3","MT 1.4","MT 1.5","MT 1.6","MT 1.7","MT 1.8","MT 1.9","MT 2","MT 2.1","MT 2.2");

var torso = 2;
var num = comb[+torso+];
```

Comment: torso will submit an number, that i want to use as index to access the the position in the array

Comment: Do you know how to access an array element without a variable? (i.e. directly using the index).

Comment: why are you putting `+` around `torso` in your statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `torso` variable as index to access an item from the `comb` array:

```
var num = comb[torso];
```

With the value `2` for `torso`, `num` will contain the third item from the array; `"MT 1.3"`.